# How do I run my python command as a cron while loading my environment vars?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron, environment-variables

I'm using Python 3.7 with Django.  I want to set up a cron job ("crontab -e") where I run

```
davea$ /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project; ./venv/bin/activate; python manage.py runstats'
```

However, upon running that, I get the error

```
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
```

If I run

```
cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project; ./venv/bin/activate; python manage.py runstats
```

everything runs fine, but I want to load environment variables which is why I was trying the former command.  Is there a way to fix the first command so that I can load my environment vars and also execute my script?  Below is my "manage.py" file ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mainpage_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc          # line 14
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Although a cron job may accomplish what you need to, but still would strongly recommend you to check out [celery beats](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: The error you're showing isn't complete. But I've seen it before, it's a syntax error isn't it? It indicates your command is running with the wrong python version (2.x system version instead of 3.x). Your command to activate the venv is wrong it should be `source ./venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten.  That was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should turn on the virtualenv with source ./venv/bin/activate
as @dirkgorten suggested